# "Out of Memory" after adding an array in Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, out-of-memory

I'm trying to trace `get_page_from_freelist()`.

I defined a pointer of integer and initialized it with `kmalloc()` in `mm/init_mm.c`, and added some system calls to control it. But after this, I rebooted my computer and saw the "Out of Memory" error.

I reduced the array size to 4KB(512 entries), but it still shows the same error message. As far as I know, 4KB size is very small to kernel. How can I handle this problem?

I think the array size or using `kmalloc()` is not the issue, because I've already try to reduce its size and allocate it statically.

My kernel version is 5.19.9 and I have 32GB physical memory. I'm using 64bit ubuntu 22.04

from `mm/init-mm.c`:

```
int trace_on;
int trace_idx;
int trace_mod;

int raw_trace[TRACE_SIZE][2];

void setup_initial_init_mm(void *start_code, void *end_code,
               void *end_data, void *brk)
{
    int i;

    trace_on = 0;
    trace_idx = 0;
    trace_mod = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < TRACE_SIZE; i++) {
        raw_trace[I][trace_mod] = 0;
    }
    init_mm.start_code = (unsigned long)start_code;
    init_mm.end_code = (unsigned long)end_code;
    init_mm.end_data = (unsigned long)end_data;
    init_mm.brk = (unsigned long)brk;
}
```

from `include/linux/mm_types.h`:

```
#define TRACE_SIZE 0x100
extern int trace_on;
extern int trace_idx;
extern int trace_mod;

extern int raw_trace[TRACE_SIZE][2];
```

from `mm/page_alloc.c`:

```
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
extern int trace_on;
extern int trace_idx;
extern int trace_mod;

extern int raw_trace[TRACE_SIZE][2];

static struct page *
get_page_from_freelist(gfp_t gfp_mask, unsigned int order, int alloc_flags,
                        const struct alloc_context *ac)
{
    struct zoneref *z;
    struct zone *zone;
    struct pglist_data *last_pgdat_dirty_limit = NULL;
    bool no_fallback;
    int i;

    if (unlikely(!trace_on && trace_idx > 0)) {
            if (unlikely(trace_idx == TRACE_SIZE))
                trace_idx--;
            for (i = 0; i <= trace_idx; i++) {
                raw_trace[i][0] = 0;
                raw_trace[i][1] = 0;

            }
            trace_idx = 0;
            trace_mod = 0;
    }
retry:
...
try_this_zone:
        page = rmqueue(ac->preferred_zoneref->zone, zone, order,
                gfp_mask, alloc_flags, ac->migratetype);
        if (page) {
            prep_new_page(page, order, gfp_mask, alloc_flags);

            /*
             * If this is a high-order atomic allocation then check
             * if the pageblock should be reserved for the future
             */
            if (unlikely(order && (alloc_flags & ALLOC_HARDER)))
                reserve_highatomic_pageblock(page, zone, order);
            if (unlikely(trace_on)) {
                if (unlikely(trace_idx >= TRACE_SIZE)) {
                    if (trace_mod)  trace_mod = 0;
                    else        trace_mod = 1;
                    trace_idx = 0;
                }
                raw_trace[trace_idx++][trace_mod] = page_to_phys(page);
            }
...
```

Comment: Without your code, how is anyone supposed to know? Clean up your changes, and push them somewhere (GitHub?) so we can look at your modification as one standalone commit atop of a known-to-work kernel

Comment: @MarcusMüller So sorry for that. I attached my modifications. Will it be enough for others to figure out?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/ maybe?